# Not getting a proper answer

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long withdraw;
    double amount;
    cin>>withdraw>>amount;
    if(withdraw>amount)
        cout<<amount;
    else if(withdraw<amount && withdraw%5==0)
    {
        amount=amount-(withdraw+0.5);  //0.5 for bank charges
        cout<<setprecision(2);
        cout<<amount;
    }
    else
        cout<<amount;
    return 0;
}
```

---

when inputs are

```
withdraw: 12.5   
amount:   300
```

output:

```
0.5
```

Not only for this input but for other inputs too, I am not getting the answer.
I searched for it but couldn't find any.Please explain and help me out.

Comment: Your title could apply to a wide multitude of questions. I'd suggest making it specific to your question.

Comment: What does `setprecision` do? Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: As a side-note:`0.5` does not stand for `5%` and `withdraw%5` does not stand for 5% of `withdraw`.

Comment: Debugging this is simple.  Print out what `withdraw` and `amount` are right after you read them. Learning to debug your own programs to find simple mistakes is something you will need to learn in order to be a successful programmer.

Comment: you could flush out the cin. So basically you discard 0.5 from buffer.

Comment: @RoshanMehta For what purpose? Either the input is incorrect or the variable types are incorrect. What you've suggested will fix neither of those problems.

Answer (score 3):

Your `withdraw` is declared with an integer type. When you attempt to read `12.5` from an input stream as an integer, only `12` is seen as matching part of the input. Only `12` is read as your `withdraw`. The `.5 300` sequence remains in the input buffer. The next read for `amount` reads that `.5`.

So, your code always reads `withdraw` as `12` and `amount` as `0.5`. That `300` is never read, never participates in anything and never affects anything.

The true branch of the first `if` is always taken, which just prints `0.5`.